# Converting Here API WKTShapeType Multipolygon To GeoJSON?

Tags: geospatial, polygon, geojson, here-api, multipolygons

I have access to a data source that looks like:

```
"Shape": {
   "_type": "WKTShapeType",
   "Value": "MULTIPOLYGON (((-128.9102 50.82492, -128.90881 50.82422, -128.90717 50.82318, -128.90566 50.82344, -128.90458 50.82304, -128.90401 50.82154, -128.90497 50.82093..."
}
```

I would like to convert the above to a format that looks like:

```
{
  "shape": [[{"lat": 39.65451, "lng": -75.78862}, {"lat": 39.65476, "lng": -75.78862}, etc...
}
```

I am not sure what the formatting names are for the two (I believe the former is **Multipolygon** and the latter is **GeoJSON**)?  The former comes from calling Here API's geocoder endpoint.  The later is stored as a JSON file.

Are there any online tools that will help me do the conversion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a custom parser built on top of the [Wicket library](https://github.com/arthur-e/Wicket).

```
import wicket from 'wicket/wicket';

const parser = (outerPolygon) => {
  const wkt = new wicket.Wkt();
  const parsePolygonData = (polygon) => {
    wkt.read(polygon);
    wkt.toJson();
    const polygons = wkt.components;
    for (let i = 0; i < polygons.length; i++) {
      for (let x = 0; x < polygons[i].length; x++) {
        if (wkt.type === 'multipolygon') {
          for (let y = 0; y < polygons[i][x].length; y++) {
            polygons[i][x][y].lat = polygons[i][x][y].y;
            delete polygons[i][x][y].y;
            polygons[i][x][y].lng = polygons[i][x][y].x;
            delete polygons[i][x][y].x;
          }
        } else {
          polygons[i][x].lat = polygons[i][x].y;
          delete polygons[i][x].y;
          polygons[i][x].lng = polygons[i][x].x;
          delete polygons[i][x].x;
        }
      }
      if (wkt.type === 'multipolygon') {
        polygons[i] = polygons[i][0];
      }
    }
    return polygons;
  };
  return parsePolygonData(outerPolygon);
};
```

Wicket reads and JSONifies the body I received via the `Shape.Value` in the Here endpoint response.  I then rearranged the lats / lngs by giving each of those values a label.

End result is something that looks like:

```
[[{"lat": 39.65451, "lng": -75.78862}, {"lat": 39.65476, "lng": -75.78862}, etc...
```